# How can I prove the sum of squares and the sum of cubes with binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, sums-of-squares

My main problem is starting. I can't "see" anything that might give me an idea to find a relationship between these two things

Thank you :)

Comment: What makes you think this *must* be proved with binomial coefficients? You asked a very similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131354/how-do-i-expand-a-binomial-coefficient-into-a-closed-form-function) last hour, which pretty much settled *that* matter.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134747/sum-of-cubes-of-binomial-coefficients   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586138/strehl-identity-for-the-sum-of-cubes-of-binomial-coefficients   http://planetmath.org/sumofpowersofbinomialcoefficients

Comment: I'm also unsure of the relationship between binomial coefficients and these sums, but it is the case that $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \binom{n+1}{2}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2 = \binom{n+1}{2}^2$, so maybe that can be a starting point? In what context did you encounter this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of cubes of binomial coefficients](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134747/sum-of-cubes-of-binomial-coefficients)

Comment: @GNUSupporter no, that question is different.

Comment: @CodeLabMaster Thank you so much. This is a problem I have to do. The context is to prove it using Pascal's identity (and in general binomial coefficients)

Comment: @dxiv not for me. Sorry. This is an exercise, and that is why I do not ask for a complete solution. Just a hint. I have to prove it using binomial coefficients.

Comment: @TheBosco You can prove $$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \binom{n+1}{2}$$ with pascal's law and induction. Perhaps you can do the same for higher exponents.

Comment: @TheBosco Sorry, I made a mistake while reading the title.

Answer (score 2):

If I may hazard a guess, perhaps you are expected to use the identities
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom k2=\binom{n+1}3$$
and
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom k3=\binom{n+1}4$$
to derive formulas for
$$\sum_{k=0}^nk^2$$
and
$$\sum_{k=0}^nk^3.$$
For instance,
$$\binom{n+1}3=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom k2=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k^2-k}2=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^nk^2-\frac12\sum_{k=0}^nk$$
so
$$\sum_{k=0}^nk^2=2\binom{n+1}3+\sum_{k=0}^nk=2\binom{n+1}3+\binom{n+1}2.$$

Answer (score 1):

The binomial coefficients appear in the expansion of powers, such as $(k-1)^2=k^2-2k+1$.

---

Now consider

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-\sum_{k=1}^n(k-1)^2.$$

One one hand, this difference is the single term $n^2$. On the other, is is a linear combination of sums of $k^d$ for $0\le d<2$ (the terms $k^2$ cancel out):

$$n^2=2\sum_{k=1}^nk-\sum_{k=1}^n1,$$ from wich you draw

$$S_2(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n^2+n}2.$$

---

You can repeat the reasoning with

$$n^3=3\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-3\sum_{k=1}^nk+\sum_{k=1}^n1$$ and
$$n^4=4\sum_{k=1}^nk^3-6\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+4\sum_{k=1}^nk-\sum_{k=1}^n1.$$

Answer (score -1):

To prove $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 = \binom{n+1}{2}^2$, use Pascal's law to find

$$\binom{n+1}{2}^2 = \left( \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1} \right)^2 = \binom{n}{2}^2 + n^3  $$

and use induction. You're likely to find the formula for sums of squares in a similar fashion.